# Is it possible to check whether any given disk sector is being accessed?

Tags: c++, windows, disk, sector

I am writing a C++ program that is currently capable of opening any drive given a disk letter ('C', 'D', etc), and then reading or writing to any sector within that drive given a sector identifier (index).

I am using the Windows File API (CreateFile, ReadFile, SetFilePointer, etc.) for achieving this thus far. Also, for insight, I calculate the offset to read from/write to, using:
`disk sector size * sector index + offset`

Now, I would like to be able to check whether any given sector (specified by an index for example), is in use by the file system already before reading from/writing to it. How could I achieve this?

I am fairly sure it isn't even possible, but, maybe someone out there knows a way.

Comment: For NTFS partitions you will need to parse the [Master File Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/master-file-table).  For other partition types [Hard drives and partitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/hard-drives-and-partitions?view=windows-11) you will need to parse their structures.  You have a lot of reading in front of you.

Comment: @RichardCritten parsing the MFT just gives you the list of files and their properties and not what sector is being opened, which is only handled by the filesystem driver. You have to hook into the driver to achieve that

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "in use". Do you mean "is not free"? Or do you mean "is not actively being read/written right now"? The title suggest the latter but the text suggests the former.

Comment: @RaymondChen that's my bad. I meant the former.

Comment: @RichardCritten you refer to "the filesystem driver" in your comment; what driver(s) are you referring to specifically? You can assume I am referring to a driver included in Windows 10 x64, if the answer differs between OS versions.

Comment: `FSCTL_GET_VOLUME_BITMAP` will tell you which clusters are allocated and which are free. It is left to you to convert clusters to sectors.